# Database design for a Fantasy league

Tags: mysql, database-design

Here's the basic schema for my database

```
Table user{  
      userid numeber primary key,  
      count number  
}

Table player{  
      pid number primary key,  
}

Table user-player{  
      userid number primary key foreign key(user),  
      pid number primary key foreign key(player)  
}

Table temp{  
      pid number primary key,  
      points number  
}
```

Here's what I intend to do...

- After every match the temp table is updated which holds the id of players that played the last match and the points they earned.

  Next run a procedure that will match the pid from temp table with every uid of user-player table having the same pid.

  add the points from temp table to the count of user table for every matching uid.

  empty temp table.

My questions is considering 200 players and 10000 users,Will this method be efficient?
I am going to be using mysql for this.

Comment: I don't get where the temp table is for. Why not update the score in the user table directly?

Comment: temp table is to put in the scores for each player after every match...manually or through some api

Comment: Temp table seems unnecessary. This is a one, maybe two query process. Heck - make an hourly cron job to query completed matches and run the 'points update'.

Comment: almost anything you do will work fine with 200 players and 10000 users, this is a very small load for a modern db

Answer (score 7, accepted):

People often seem to be worried about performance for small databases.  *Let the DBMS do what it is designed to do.*  If you find in practice - or preferably under load testing - that you have a performance problem, then take steps to deal with it.  Otherwise **don't pre-optimize**!

Instead of using a temporary table to store one batch of player scores, **store all player scores in a tranactional table.**

Remove the `user.count` column and replace your `temp` table with something like this:

```
Table player_points{  
      pid number primary key,  
      match_date datetime primary key, 
      points number
}
```

With this you can easily calculate any user's score.  You can even recalculate any user's score as of a given date.  This is much more powerful and much simpler to maintain.  Keeping a current snapshot only makes it impossible to manage should anything go wrong or should one of your users challenge their score.

This query gives you the scores for all users.  You can add filters to it to do other things like finding the score for a single user or showing a leader board.

```
select 
  U.userid as UserID
, sum(S.points) as TotalScore
from user S 
  inner join user-player J
    on S.userid = J.userid
  inner join player_points S
    on J.pid = S.pid
group by
  U.userid
```

This query would give you a leader board:

```
select 
  U.userid as UserID
, sum(S.points) as TotalScore
from user S 
  inner join user-player J
    on S.userid = J.userid
  inner join player_points S
    on J.pid = S.pid
group by
  U.userid
order by TotalScore desc
limit 10
```

This query would give you points awarded to a user by date, which you could graph as-is or cumulatively, for example.

```
select 
  S.match_date as MatchDate
, sum(S.points) as TotalScore
from user-player J
  inner join player_points S
    on J.pid = S.pid
where J.userid = 123 -- The user ID you want.
group by
  S.match_date 
order by S.match_date
```